# change the number of parallel threads dynamically

Tags: python, multithreading, networking, optimization

I've a program that need to do a lot of queries over the network, so what I'm doing is to parallelize the work. It is really I/O-bounded, I'm simply doing:

```
for i in range(options.workers):
    w = Worker(queue, output_queue, options.site)
    w.setDaemon(True)
    w.start()

for i, dataset_metadata in enumerate(datasets_metadata):
    queue.put((i+1, dataset_metadata))

queue.join()
```

the `options.workers` comes from the command line. Now I want to dynamically change the number of works.

First question: how to add workers after `queue.join`?

Second question: how to evaluate the optimal number of workers at run time? I think I've to monitor the speed tasks/time, increase the number of workers until this ratio doesn't change.

Comment: Make sure you understand downside of using threads with python. Read about [GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

Comment: @Vikas: as i said my problem is I/O bounded

Answer (score 1):

You probably could start and stop your workers yourself, but much of the functionality you need is probably already available:

- the [`multiprocessing.dummy`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing#module-multiprocessing.dummy) module exports the same API as `multithreading`, only implemented with threads instead of processes. 
  That means you can use a [`Pool`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing#using-a-pool-of-workers) of workers already implemented, and it would make it easy to switch from threading to multiprocessing if that should be needed at some point.
- The [`concurrent.futures`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/concurrent.futures) API offers a even more advanced concurrency model. It's in the standard library in python3.2+, but there are [backports](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures) for earlier versions.